# MenuItemsControl Use Derived Type For Items

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a type derived from MenuItem.  I would like that type to be used when generating submenu items from MenuItem.ItemsSource.

Here is a XAML sample that creates an item of the correct type, but wraps it inside of another MenuItem.  I would like to get rid of the wrapping MenuItem.

```
    <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:MenuItemDerived Header="{Binding Name}" Property1="{Binding Prop1}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
```

Can I change the type of the generated children to a derived type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you only need to override the MenuItem control template to make a custom item rather than subclassing MenuItem. However, it is possible to do what you are asking and change what type of sub menu items are generated. There are two ways to do it, depending on your use case.

1. Set up an `ItemContainerTemplate` for each type of item that will be in the menu. Assuming you are populating it with instances of a class called `MyItem`, you would do this:

   ```
   <MenuItem Header="Test" UsesItemContainerTemplate="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
       <MenuItem.Resources>
           <ItemContainerTemplate
               DataType="{x:Type local:MyItem}">
               <local:MenuItemDerived />
           </ItemContainerTemplate>
       </MenuItem.Resources>
   </MenuItem>
   ```

   You can add as many there as you want, one for each type of item that could be in the menu (usually there is only one).
2. Use an `ItemContainerTemplateSelector` to use whatever custom logic you want to select templates. This is good if you simply want every generated item to use the same menu item type since the first option won't allow that (you can't use `Object` as the data type for a data template). It is also necessary if you want to base the template selection off of custom logic that is more complicated than checking the type of the item.

   ```
   <MenuItem Header="Test" UsesItemContainerTemplate="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
       <MenuItem.ItemContainerTemplateSelector>
           <local:MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <local:MenuItemDerived />
               </DataTemplate>
           </local:MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector>
       </MenuItem.ItemContainerTemplateSelector>
   </MenuItem>
   ```

   The very simple `MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector` class I used there looks like this:

   ```
   [ContentProperty("Template")]
   internal class MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector : ItemContainerTemplateSelector
   {
       public DataTemplate Template { get; set; }

       public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, ItemsControl parentItemsControl)
       {
           return Template;
       }
   }
   ```

   You can, of course, make a complex selector with several templates to choose from if you want to.

Note the usage of the `UsesItemContainerTemplate` property in both cases. That needs to be true for any custom item container templates to work.

Comment: Option 1 worked like a charm.  Thanks for providing such a complete answer.